# Wordpress crashes when upgrading to PHP5.5

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, debian, php-5.5

I have a wordpress hosted on a Debian 7 server with nginx. Yesterday I've upgraded from PHP5.4 to PHP5.5 and it crashes all wordpress websites hosted. Other website using PHP works great but not wordpress.

I've tried to set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` but no errors are shown.

I've also tried `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but still a blank page.

Nginx virtual hosts

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name thinkcreate.fr www.thinkcreate.fr;

    root /var/www/blog/thinkcreate;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/thinkcreate.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/thinkcreate.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Access log

`129.10.115.241 - - [01/Dec/2015:00:33:35 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
129.10.115.241 - - [01/Dec/2015:00:33:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
173.252.74.122 - - [01/Dec/2015:00:47:58 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Taccos.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3513 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
208.80.194.125 - - [01/Dec/2015:01:03:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Opera 8.01"
83.193.129.142 - - [01/Dec/2015:01:12:21 +0100] "GET /culture-tbs/100-raisons-de-choisir-tbs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
208.80.194.125 - - [01/Dec/2015:01:47:33 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
159.203.126.129 - - [01/Dec/2015:02:12:28 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.122 Safari/537.36"
159.203.126.129 - - [01/Dec/2015:02:12:31 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C14$
158.69.2.151 - - [01/Dec/2015:05:00:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
69.61.12.70 - - [01/Dec/2015:06:34:37 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "" "Mozilla/5.0 CommonCrawler Node X3JCAGS6ANHNBVL7L2BNXPLODC5ROPX7IOEOGDBOXMHVU7E54OOENGKAHHRQ7FR.NTUMR5IV4.2OLPPTWFPSTLQQZBJ4VTQ23YHRR4FAXO6$
173.252.90.124 - - [01/Dec/2015:07:05:14 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Sun-Rise.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7576 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
173.252.73.109 - - [01/Dec/2015:07:05:39 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Sun-Rise.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7576 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
46.4.123.172 - - [01/Dec/2015:07:20:23 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)"
46.4.123.172 - - [01/Dec/2015:07:20:26 +0100] "GET /ajouter/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)"
46.4.123.172 - - [01/Dec/2015:07:20:35 +0100] "GET /partenariat/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)"
213.239.194.228 - - [01/Dec/2015:10:34:11 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://amsterjob.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
206.253.226.23 - - [01/Dec/2015:11:13:50 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; oBot/2.3.1; http://filterdb.iss.net/crawler/)"
206.253.226.23 - - [01/Dec/2015:11:13:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; oBot/2.3.1; http://filterdb.iss.net/crawler/)"
49.2.29.21 - - [01/Dec/2015:12:18:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
49.2.29.21 - - [01/Dec/2015:12:18:56 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://thinkcreate.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.8$
69.61.12.70 - - [01/Dec/2015:12:30:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "" "Mozilla/5.0 CommonCrawler Node PXF3HUDHAYL6PUCEXAQGFZF3FM4EUVBHD53XR3WTMXF5VN4CLW6PTHAZ2AV6AMG.7DJ4ZCG5S.TX4SIKGC4KPQYTLHTW6PMRQ7G4NT5WDVU$
5.175.193.164 - - [01/Dec/2015:12:58:02 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
5.175.193.164 - - [01/Dec/2015:12:58:27 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
66.220.156.114 - - [01/Dec/2015:13:01:07 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Toulouse-Debating-Society-180x180.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 7302 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatex$
66.249.85.205 - - [01/Dec/2015:13:08:05 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Google favicon"
5.175.193.164 - - [01/Dec/2015:13:19:14 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
69.171.230.117 - - [01/Dec/2015:13:48:51 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Taccos.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3513 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
31.13.110.100 - - [01/Dec/2015:13:48:51 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Sun-Rise.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7576 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
62.210.205.190 - - [01/Dec/2015:14:37:56 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "http://www.bing.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
212.99.31.8 - - [01/Dec/2015:15:05:03 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
212.99.31.8 - - [01/Dec/2015:15:05:04 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://thinkcreate.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/5$
141.212.122.128 - - [01/Dec/2015:15:17:35 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
77.201.200.125 - - [01/Dec/2015:16:58:27 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
77.201.200.125 - - [01/Dec/2015:16:58:28 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://thinkcreate.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.24$`

Nothing in error log.

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'crashes the website' any errors or just blank page? If phpinfo is blank then WP_DEBUG wont show anything either

Comment: No error prompt in my logs either...

Comment: did you try this. In one of the WP sites, rename the .htaccess file, create a new file test.php with content phpinfo(), whts the output?

Comment: Still a blank page... During the upgrade PHP asked me if I wanted to keep my php.ini (PHP 5.4) configuration. I said yes, so I've a PHP 5.5 running with my "old" php.ini conf. Maybe there is something there.

Comment: a blank page or request timeout? Can you open your nginx virtualhost or server config and open the file `error_log` points to? Better would be to update your answer with nginx config and the last 10-20 lines from `access_log` and `error_log` files. Are your requests being tracked in `access_log`?

Comment: The blank page is instantaneous. @Alexey I've updated my answer.

Comment: what does `netstat -apn|grep 80` show?

Comment: I have 7 entries tcp: `0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*           
0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*           
127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:37247     
127.0.0.1:37247         127.0.0.1:8080      
37.187.123.142:80       66.249.64.97:41741  
37.187.123.142:80       82.227.214.50:53441 
37.187.123.142:80       37.115.184.194:58602` and 5 entries unix: `113647504 25805/php-fpm.conf)
115428000 19675/nginx
115428001 19675/nginx
113647505 25805/php-fpm.conf)
115428002 19675/nginx`

Answer (score -1):

My ISP just upgraded my server from 5.3 to 5.5 Php interpreter. I was able to move between the two (using htaccss) as I did code repairs/updates. In my case, and since most of my pages are interactive, it was necessary to rewrite certain parts of my pages to adhere to 5.5's requirement for handling variables from page to page. Otherwise the pages would come up blank (no info from database) or pass an error on the page. I don't know a lot about wordpress at all, but if you are dealing only with the php side of things, maybe you just need a few tweaks here and there. My entire domain is up to speed now. It took about 4 weeks of updating my code,but again I have a very large domain.

Comment: Where did you end up needing to make the most changes? Can you give examples that helped get the site going again?